# Ubuntu mount-point map Windows Share gets permissions denied error

Tags: ubuntu, mount, cifs, share, smbfs

We have an EMC storage appliance that serves Windows Shares via CIFS protocol.

On Ubuntu I need to create a mount-point that maps the Windows Share.

When I run this shell script :

```
sudo apt-get install -y smbfs
sudo mkdir -p /mapdir 
sudo mount -t smbfs -o username=domain/user,password=password //server/share /mapdir
```

I receive this error :

> ```
> mount error(13): Permission denied
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
> ```

The domain/user and password are known to be correct.

What are potential causes of the permission denied error ?

Could passing plain-text credentials not apply in this scenario ?

Comment: A simple first stage debug is run `sudo -i` first and then run the mount command, to confirm if `sudo` is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to not escaping the slashes. Below command has worked for me:

```
sudo mount -t cifs \\\\usrc-drm\\upgrades /mnt/win -o user=myusername,pass=mypassword
```

I'm also doing this on ubuntu

For troubleshooting, try mounting the same share from a windows machine, see if that works.